# using free-form composer - form not appearing correctly

Tags: solspace-freeform

using tag:
{exp:freeform:composer form_name="test"}

It draws lines but doesn't show the form inputs
example:
http://sellitresolution.com/home/test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you view source, you'll see that all the Freeform code is there. This seems to be more of a display issue. Try that tag in a blank template and see what you get.

Comment: Turned out an issue to be with my style conflicting with composer. I'm still running down the exact line but you got me thinking!

Comment: you can create your own custom composer template to associate with the form if the stock one is causing issues.